# DDE - Mail Merge From Excel to Word 2016 using OpenDataSource

Tags: vba

I have a old legacy code which is programmed for mail merge. I have a add-in code to populate xls file which in turn should merge the data to word template defined. Code snippet :

```
Public Sub ProcessForSharePoint(DataSource As Object, MainDoc As Document)
    Dim tempPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim recordCount As Integer
    Dim ActualCount As Integer
    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim tempName As String
    Dim rowEmpty As Boolean 
    On Error GoTo tempFileError
    tempName = Left(MainDoc.name, InStrRev(MainDoc.name, ".") - 1)
    tempPath = Environ("TEMP") + "\" + tempName + ".xls"
    If (Dir(tempPath) <> "") Then
      SetAttr tempPath, vbNormal
      Kill tempPath
    End If
    
    DataSource.SaveAs (tempPath)
    
    On Error GoTo openDataSourceError
    MainDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource tempPath, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, 
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, Revert:=False, Connection:="Entire Spreadsheet", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeWord2000

    recordCount = 0
    On Error GoTo wsError
    Set ws = DataSource.WorkSheets(1)
    
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    
    ' Work out how many rows we have to process
    For r = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        rowEmpty = True
        For c = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c)) Then
                rowEmpty = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        
        If rowEmpty Then
            Exit For
        End If
        recordCount = recordCount + 1
    Next r
    GoTo DoMerge
 
wsError:
    GoTo CloseMerge
    
DoMerge:
    ActualCount = 0
    If (recordCount = 0) Then
            OutputDebugString "PSLWordDV: ProcessForSharePoint: No records to process"
            GoTo CloseMerge
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo mergeError
    For i = 1 To recordCount
            ' .Destination  0 = DOCUMENT, 1 = PRINTER
            MainDoc.MailMerge.Destination = 0 'wdSendToNewDocument
            MainDoc.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = True
            With MainDoc.MailMerge.DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = i     'wdDefaultFirstRecord
                    .LastRecord = i    'wdDefaultLastRecord
                    .ActiveRecord = i
            End With
            
            
            MainDoc.MailMerge.Execute Pause:=False
            Populate MainDoc, ActiveDocument
            ActualCount = ActualCount + 1
    Next i
    GoTo CloseMerge
```

When I call this function, my xls files gets open and populate data (I want data from Sheet 1 only). Then my WORD opens (OpenDataSource) and on selection of "Yes" for population on Word --> My code fails and catches the error "462".

On further analysis (not sure correct or not), it seems, there is a problem in :
Set ws = DataSource.WorkSheets(1)
NOTE: If I hard code my recordCount variable to 1 (say) -> merging process works absolutely fine.

Can anyone please help on priority to sort my client issue please.